# Create array for runtime from union type

Tags: typescript, union-types

Let's say that I have the following union type:

```
type Browser = 'Chrome' | 'Firefox'
```

And I want to create an array out of it:

```
const browsers = /* code to transform Browser type in ['Chrome', 'Firefox']
```

The idea is to use it on runtime. Is there a way? I've tried with `key of` but of course it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might want to use an [enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html):

```
enum Browser {
    Chrome = 'Chrome',
    Firefox = 'Firefox',
}

const browsers = Object.values(Browser);
```

Answer (score 0):

Typescript annotations don't exist at runtime so there is no way to create an array from a type at runtime.

On the other hand if the intention is to only write the list of browsers once:

```js
const browsers = ['Chrome', 'Firefox'] as const;
type Browser = typeof browsers[number] // "Chrome" | "Firefox"
```